# Network does not converge after creating a simple identity layer in pycaffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent, pycaffe

This is a simple layer which would pass the bottom blob to the top and do nothing else.

```
import caffe
import numpy as np

class MyCustomLayer(caffe.Layer):
def setup(self, bottom, top):
    if len(bottom) != 1:
        raise Exception("Wrong number of bottom blobs")



def forward(self, bottom, top):
    top[0].data[...] = bottom[0].data




def reshape(self, bottom, top):
    top[0].reshape(*bottom[0].shape)



    pass

def backward(self, propagate_down, bottom, top):


    """
        This layer does not back propagate
    """

    pass
```

However, when used in a network, the network won't converge and would stay at `0.1` accuracy (whereas prior to using this layer it was 0.75%)
What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect your net to converge if you do not backprop gradient? You need to implement `backward` as well:

```
def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
  bottom[0].diff[...] = top[0].diff
```

Note that the input arguments to `backward()` are different than the other methods and different than what you wrote in the question.